# What's the meaning of "Not that you'd know it."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I watched a documentary about Dholes, the Asiatic wild dog.

> It says "Dholes are deadly hunters. Not that you'd know it."

I'd like to know what "Not that you'd know it" mean?

Comment: It's a contraction for "Not that you **would know** [that the Dholes are deadly hunters] it"

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "Not that you'd know it" means that their nature as "deadly hunters" is not immediately apparent from observing either their looks or behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It means that they've got some feature e.g. poison or venom that is not immediately visible, but 'deadly'.  In dholes, I believe the 'hidden feature' is [speed and stamina.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhole)